# Is the SKStoreReviewController API also available for MacOS, and if yes, how to implement it?

Tags: swift, macos

I am using the SKStoreReviewController API in my iOS app to get reviews of my app. I also wanted to implement this into my MacOS app, but it seems that this is not possible. I imported StoreKit, but it says "Use of unresolved identifier 'SKStoreReviewController'". Do I need to implement this differently, or is this not meant to be used for the Mac Appstore?

Comment: I'm considering using push notifications to request reviews.  If a user is far enough along in my app to be signed up for notifications they must be using it enough to review it in my opinion.  What did you end up doing?

Comment: I ended up with a dialog when starting the app asking for a review, which would open the browser and direct them to the itunes app website... found no better solution

Comment: Available since macOS 10.14+

Answer (score 5):

As Marek pointed out, the `SKStoreReviewController` class is available since macOS 10.14+.

> Use the `requestReview()` method to indicate when it makes sense within the logic of your app to ask the user for ratings and reviews within your app.

Apple still recommends in the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/system-capabilities/ratings-and-reviews/) to don't use buttons or other controls to request feedback and trigger, but trigger it only in other situations.

Apple has a nice [example code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/requesting_app_store_reviews) to handle the review showing only for specific actions:

```
// If the count has not yet been stored, this will return 0
var count = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.processCompletedCountKey)
count += 1
UserDefaults.standard.set(count, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.processCompletedCountKey)

print("Process completed \(count) time(s)")

// Get the current bundle version for the app
let infoDictionaryKey = kCFBundleVersionKey as String
guard let currentVersion = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: infoDictionaryKey) as? String
    else { fatalError("Expected to find a bundle version in the info dictionary") }

let lastVersionPromptedForReview = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.lastVersionPromptedForReviewKey)

// Has the process been completed several times and the user has not already been prompted for this version?
if count >= 4 && currentVersion != lastVersionPromptedForReview {
    let twoSecondsFromNow = DispatchTime.now() + 2.0
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: twoSecondsFromNow, execute: { 
        SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(currentVersion, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.lastVersionPromptedForReviewKey)
    })
}
```

Even though when I only call `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` there's no review prompt appearing. Does anyone know a a specific trick for macOS?

**Edit: I've submitted an update to the app store and the review prompt is working! I don't know why it's not appearing when testing, but in production it seems to work!**

Answer (score 0):

`SKStoreReviewController` is for iOS only as seen in the "SDK" section of the 
[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller).

[image: sdk]

To let users write reviews, you will have to use the link to the Mac App Store.

```
let appid = 9999999999 // put your app id here
if let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id\?(appid)ls=1&mt=8&action=write-review") {
    NSWorkspace.shared().open(url) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave this a try, but the created link doesn't work for me. Can you please give me a sample url which should result of this code?

Comment: Available since macOS 10.14+

Answer (score 0):

**SKStoreReviewController**  is available even on macOS 10.14+, but sometimes i wasn't able to make it work with `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` so I use the manual mode that you can find here:

```
let appId = 1547575778 //Your app Id from the Itunes Connect portal
if let url = URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/app/id\(appId)?action=write-review") {
     NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SKStoreReviewController is available since macOS 10.14

You can use my tiny wrapper:

```
// Review after 3 launches
AppReview.requestIf(launches: 3)

// Review after 5 days
AppReview.requestIf(days: 5)

// Review after 3 launches and 5 days
AppReview.requestIf(launches: 3, days: 5)
```

https://github.com/mezhevikin/AppReview